# Smart Card Authentication Between VMware and Teradici

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware

So, here's the rub:

I have a zero client and I'm using Teradici. I have a Windows 10 image. Starting with the zero client, I am able to log in and authenticate with my smartcard, pick my connection server, select my pool, and then I am brought to a machine. The problem is that the machine doesn't seem to recognize my smartcard - or that I even have one.

The way it *should* work is that once I select a pool, my credentials on the smart card are passed from authenticating with the zero clients to the virtual machine. That is, at the Windows login screen, it will notice my smart card and log me in without me having to re-enter my credentials. Right now, I'm just taken to an empty prompt for a username and password.

Couple things to note:

1. Yes, the smartcard reader/smart card *is* supported. We are able to have our desired result work with another Windows 7 parent image.
2. I have spent hours working with VMware and Teradici. Both keep pointing fingers at each other.
3. Yes, I checked to make sure the PCoiP smart card option was installed with View Agent.
4. The machines from the Windows 10 parent image are created in the same OU as the machines from the working parent image. I.e. group policy should be same on both of those.
   5.)I have compared between the working parent image and the new parent image and we can't seem to find out what the problem is.

On a side note, we can't even get this to work on another Windows 7 image, so even if it's something to do with Windows 10, we still can't get this to work on other Windows 7 images.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up finally finding the issue after much testing. The solution was to install an the older version of View Agent (versions 6.2). And of course, I made sure that the PCoiP option was selected in addition to USB redirection (not sure if USB redirection really matters). Using View Agent 7 or above will essentially break this important functionality.